# Spring-boot: set default value to configurable properties

Tags: java, properties, spring-boot, configurationproperty

I have a properties class below in my spring-boot project.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprefix")
public class MyProperties {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;

    // getter/setter
}
```

Now, I want to set default value to some other property in my application.properties file for `property1`. Similar to what below example does using @Value

```
@Value("${myprefix.property1:${somepropety}}")
private String property1;
```

I know we can assign static value just like in example below where "default value" is assigned as default value for `property`,

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprefix")
public class MyProperties {
    private String property1 = "default value"; // if it's static value
    private String property2;

    // getter/setter
}
```

How to do this using @ConfigurationProperties class (rather typesafe configuration properties) in spring boot where my default value is another property ?

Comment: Please, view this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220498/why-is-configurationproperties-not-overriding-defaults-in-my-case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220498/why-is-configurationproperties-not-overriding-defaults-in-my-case)

Answer (score 8):

Check if property1 was set using a @PostContruct in your MyProperties class. If it wasn't you can assign it to another property.

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if(property1==null) {
            property1 = //whatever you want
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solved my problem for now. But, I think spring should provide support for the same just like @Value.

Comment: I was searching on how to set defaults and this was about the only answer I could find .. but [on this wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding#default-value) it seems you can set a default value for your property like you would expect.

Answer (score 4):

In spring-boot 1.5.10 (and possibly earlier) setting a default value works as-per your suggested way. Example:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprefix")
public class MyProperties {

  @Value("${spring.application.name}")
  protected String appName;
}
```

The `@Value` default is only used if not overridden in your own property file.

Comment: Thank you, yet how would one parse the parameter values form the properties file this way? E.g., how can I ensure that a specific value is indeed an Integer and in the range of 5-8?

Comment: @Xenonite: Add `@Validated` to the class and then use the existing `javax.validation.constraints.*` annotations on the fields or create some of your own if what's provided is insufficient.

Comment: It is not recommended to mix both behaviors.