# Spring conversion service not getting initialized correctly for test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-config

I am using spring boot 1.5.9 to write a small rest server. I have just started of with initialization code and got stuck with this weird behavior.

I have a small test -

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestMongo {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOps; 

    @Test
    public void testMongoConnection() {
        assertFalse(mongoOps.collectionExists("test"));
    }
}
```

Initially, the application.properties were being ignored. After I added the @SpringBootTest annotation, the application.properties were read but the following error started occurring.

> Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult:
>   1 errors Field error in object 'mongo' on field 'port': rejected value
>   [${mongo.port:27017}]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.mongo.port,typeMismatch.port,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [mongo.port,port]; arguments []; default message [port]];
>   default message [Failed to convert property value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'port'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to
>   type [int]]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.checkForBindingErrors(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:359)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:276)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:240)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:330)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]    ... 56 common frames
>   omitted

I have tried this declaring port as java.lang.Integer as well as int.

The configuration beans look like this -

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MongoProperties.class)
public class SpringConfiguration {

    private MongoProperties mongoPropertiesConfiguration;

    public MongoProperties getMongoConfiguration() {
        return mongoPropertiesConfiguration;
    }


    @Autowired
    public void setMongoConfiguration(MongoProperties mongoConfiguration) {
        this.mongoPropertiesConfiguration = mongoConfiguration;
    }



    public @Bean MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient(mongoPropertiesConfiguration.getHost(), mongoPropertiesConfiguration.getPort());
    }

    public @Bean MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient(), mongoPropertiesConfiguration.getDb());
    }

    public @Bean MongoOperations mongoOperations() {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

And

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="mongo")
public class MongoProperties {

    private String host;
    private Integer port;
    private String db;

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }
    public Integer getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    public void setPort(Integer port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    public String getDb() {
        return db;
    }
    public void setDb(String db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

}
```

I did get the test running with @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation instead of @SpringBootTest. But that worked just for one of the tests. I think it matters in which package your test is and I think that @EnableAutoConfiguration may not be the right approach.

I have been debugging the spring source for some time now, without any leads.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

EDIT 1:
As requested, adding the application.properties

```
mongo.host=localhost
mongo.port=${mongo.port:27017}
mongo.db=${mongo.db:synctool}
```

Comment: what is in application.properties/.yaml?

Comment: @spi added the contents of application.properties.

Comment: It looks like there are no converters getting registered with the conversion service. But I don't know why?

Comment: not sure about your syntax (never seen that before)... try with ```mongo.port=27017``` instead

Comment: @spi THe syntax is ok. I have got it working with that syntax once when using \@EnableAutoConfiguration. I have also tried your suggestion to no avail with \@SpringBootTest.

Comment: what if you temporary type your field "port" to a striing? and use ```Integer.parseInt``` at the required place. just to see if everything works, and to debug your beans more easily

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162123/discussion-between-user1676688-and-spi).

Comment: What's the value of `mongo.port` that you're getting? Use the debugger and find out. Also, don't hold me to it, but I think for `ConfigurationProperties` to work, you need a `SpringBootApplication` to be found by the test.

Comment: I love when you try to help people and they suddendtly stop to answer...

Comment: @spi Apologies for the late reply. I was travelling yesterday. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I am getting the value as null.

Answer (score -1):

not sure about your syntax

> mongo.port=${mongo.port:27017}

spring try to convert *${mongo.port:27017}* to your MongoProperties.port Integer property

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'port'

if you want to set some default value to your property
see [Spring-boot: set default value to configurable properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882541/spring-boot-set-default-value-to-configurable-properties)

Comment: This is not an answer. If you wanna guess, use comments.